# Android Java - programmatically capture background before app window opens

Tags: java, android, image, imageview

I'm attempting to create an Android Java app that has a background image that is the blurred background of the device (before the app opens) and then display a dialog on top of the background.

The effect would be that it looks like the app is simply blurring the background and displaying a dialog on top of the display. But in reality the app is full-screen but has captured and blurred the background.

I've followed many tutorials of how to grab a screenshot programatically in Android but the screenshot is always of the running application. Not the background (what's on the screen) before the application opens.

Any pointers in how to achieve this?

Comment: I would have to think that's a security concern, where a developer could take a snapshot of potentially private data. Without knowing, I'd be surprised if this would be allowed by the OS or the language itself.

Comment: Definitely a security concern.